# How can I use native capabilities in progressive web apps (PWAs)?

Tags: web-apps, javascript

I'm trying to develop two separate web apps with each geofencing and inter-app communication features. These are features that the [web does *not* support today](https://whatwebcando.today/). I want to use the PWA option mostly because of the ease of "Add to Home" and also because only one native feature is needed for each of the apps.

I searched for resources on how to use native features on PWAs, but couldn't find any except for comparisons between frameworks such as: react native, flutter, nativescript, ionic and a few others. I thought maybe nativescript in PWAs will work, but can't figure out how.

Which software option would you recommend? PWAs, NativeScript, or a mixture of both?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Please note this site is about recommending *software,* not assets or [resources](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2470/185) like [howtos](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/882/185), [manuals/tutorials](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1258/185),[code fragments](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/904/185), etc.

Comment: @Izzy Thank you! I edited the question, but would it better to ask it on stackoverflow? Have a great day :)

Comment: Now it looks like you ask for a progamming language, which is also off-topic here (see: [Should programming language recommendations be allowed here?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/36/185)). Not being active at SO I'm not sure if it fits there – but it seems it doesn't fit here either.

Comment: @Izzy Please note that Nativescript is not a programming language, but a framework. PWAs are also a kind of framework for building web apps. Frameworks are libraries so I'm sure this question is not off-topic according to the link you gave me.

Comment: Thanks for explaining! I'm not sure if it has sufficient details (see: [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185)) But not being familiar in that area, I'll reopen and let those decide who are.

Comment: Thank you very much @Izzy! I'll edit the question by the link you gave me. May I ask, is there a reading list for beginners to ask better questions? I would love to read it through and edit further questions accordingly. Thanks again @Izzy

Comment: I don't know of such a reading list. But one good starting point you already know by now. Another is our [help] (check the "Asking" section) – and then there are our [answered questions on question-quality](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bquestion-quality%5D+answers%3A1) on our Meta site. Guess that should get you started. And thanks for asking!